# Nifi Updaterecord removes leading zero from a record

Tags: csv, apache-nifi

When I use UpdateRecord processor for removing some certain integers from a number and add leading 0.

Queued values verify leading 0 is there ,But after the process, I use another Update record processor for adding a new column using previously changed column.

My configurations are as followed.

**menu**
[image]

**csv reader**
[image]

**csv writter**
[image]

In values, this process also replaces leading 0 in original column too. How can I keep this value as its after the processor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not infer a schema for your case when you read the CSV. If you did that then the number values will be treated as an integer and it will remove the leading zeros. Try with `Use String Fields From Header` option.